# Php improving performance of large data loops

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have large list of data about 60000 rows in Excel (.xlsx) i am inserting all the data in MySQL using **Spout** library to read Excel data and after reading data from excel file there are some details which is not in Unicode format and also not in English (current data is in Hindi language) so first i am converting this non standard text to Unicode using a **Python** script and then finally converting Unicode data Hindi  to English using **Google Translate API**..everything is working fine but its taking so much time. In my current script 200 Rows inserted in MySQL after all these steps and it takes about 20 Minutes..my question is how can i improve my current script for more performance
**This is my current script:**

```
// Convert local hindi font to unicode
function KridevToUnicode($k) {
    $myfile =  fopen("input.txt", "w");
    fwrite($myfile, $k);
    fclose($myfile);
    shell_exec('krutidev2unicode.py -i input.txt -o output.txt');
    $file = fopen("output.txt","r");
    return hindiToEnglish(fgets($file));
    fclose($file);
}
// Convert hindi to english
function hindiToEnglish($text) {
    $apiKey2 = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' . $apiKey2 . '&q=' . rawurlencode($text) . '&source=hi&target=en';
    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($handle);                 
    $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
    curl_close($handle);
    return $responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
}
//Read data from Excel and insert in MySQL
require_once 'Spout/Autoloader/autoload.php';
use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;
use Box\Spout\Common\Type;
$reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX); 
$reader->open('a.xlsx');
foreach($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
    foreach($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        ob_start();
        $i++;
        $membershipNumber = $row[1];
        $memberName = KridevToUnicode($row[3]);
        $fatherHusbandName = KridevToUnicode($row[4]);
        if(is_string($row[5])) {
            $dob = '';
        }else {
            $dob = $row[5]->format('d-m-Y');
            $dob = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dob));
        }
        $permanentAddress = KridevToUnicode($row[6]);
        $currentAddress = KridevToUnicode($row[7]);
        $district = KridevToUnicode($row[8]);
        $state = KridevToUnicode($row[10]);
        $pincode = $row[11];
        $mobile = $row[13];
        $email = $row[14];
        $Shasan = KridevToUnicode($row[15]);
        $Occupation = KridevToUnicode($row[16]);
        $education = KridevToUnicode($row[17]);
        $Inspiration = KridevToUnicode($row[18]);
        $ReceiptNo = $row[19];
        if(is_string($row[20])) {
            $DateofReceipt = '';
        }else {
            $DateofReceipt = $row[20]->format('d-m-Y');
            $DateofReceipt = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($DateofReceipt));
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (membershipNumber, name, father_husband_name, dob, permanent_address, current_address, district, state, pin_code, phone, email, shasan, profession, education, inspiration, receiptNo, DateofReceipt)
        VALUES ('$membershipNumber', '$memberName', '$fatherHusbandName', '$dob', '$permanentAddress', '$currentAddress', '$district', '$state', '$pincode', '$mobile', '$email', '$Shasan', '$Occupation', '$education', '$Inspiration', '$ReceiptNo', '$DateofReceipt')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
        echo ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_flush();
    }
}
$reader->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: First of all: is this a recurrent thing? Or do you only need to upload the list once? Because then it's probably easier to export the thing to .csv in Excel and import it in PhpMyAdmin or w/e portal you use.

Comment: i need to upload once but all data is not in 1 Excel file data is is multiple files and also all Excel files don't have same format

Comment: @Loek That would not allow for doing all the ___time consuming___ language conversion and Unicode changes !

Comment: If you were to time the section that does the call out to Google translate, I would expect that to be the most time consuming part of your process. You are not going to be able to increase the speed of that, even if you offered to pay google

Comment: and i can not upload directly from Excel or CSV first data need  to be covert in Unicode and the Hindi to English Traslation

Comment: However, you could split the process and do the translations and unicode conversions offline so to speak in a batch process. The overall time taken would not improve, but at least you can then just throw the data at MySQL in one simple process.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  i know i can not double the speed but i was wondering if it can increase by 10 to 20%

Comment: You could even get the batch process to generate simple SQL INSERTS and run the update from the terminal using a simple `mysql ..... < insert.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a mass insert query and execute it when you're finished creating the query.
You can insert multiple values with an insert, make your query like that and execute it when it is done

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp) is how